# Append two tables with different sizes

Tags: dax

I have table one with 5 columns and table two with 7 columns.
How can I append them into a new table with only the common columns (that is, the columns with common names)?
I tried all sorts of "Append Queries" in the Query Editor but it seems that it only works with exactly identical tables.
In DAX, UNION seems to have the same limitation.

Comment: What tool are you in Power BI Desktop? Excel?

Comment: In the Query Editor in Power BI Desktop the "Append as New" handles mismatched columns names well in my experience.

Answer (score 0):

Use Append Queries -> Append as New to create a new table.

The M function, Table.Combine(), will combine the columns where they are named the same and add columns with null values where they only exist in one table

```
Table.Combine({
    Table.FromRecords({[Name = "David", Phone = "01235667886"]}),
    Table.FromRecords({[Email= "me@gmail.com", Phone = "01124892522"]})
})


> Name   Phone        Email
> David  01235667886        
>        01124892522  me@gmail.com
```